# How to create a text line with all entries of a list? in R

Tags: r, list, text

I have a list that can have any possible length (the content of each element is not important):

```
list<- as.list(rep(NA,sample(1:10,1)))
```

I would like to create a text line in R, like this:

```
list[[1]],list[[2]],......,list[[n]]
```

being "n" the number of elements of the list.

so, if it has 4 elements I want to see appear in the console, something like this:

```
list[[1]],list[[2]],list[[3]],list[[4]]
```

so, if it has 2 elements I would like something like this:

```
list[[1]],list[[2]]
```

any idea?

Thank you very much in advance.

Tina

Comment: Just curious,  why do you want that output?

Comment: then I have a problem, as I don't really know how to explain it any better :( . I need this to pass this into another function, that only accepts arguments in this way.

Comment: What function are you passing it to?  If it's custom, then you may want to rethink *that* function

Comment: akrun, in this way you propose I get the contents of each element, but I would like to have the text exactly as specified in the question.

Comment: Indeed if there is no way to do this, I'll have to rethink the function...

Comment: @user18441 Can you show the function.

Comment: awesome akrun, thank you text=paste0("c(", paste("list[[",seq_along(list),"]]", sep='', collapse=", "), ")")->x this is exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try

```
paste0("c(", paste("list[[",seq_along(list),"]]", 
                       sep='', collapse=", "), ")")
```

Answer (score 2):

This will deliver the desired string and could easily be made into a function:

```
> paste( sprintf("list[[%i]]", 1:4) , collapse=",")
[1] "list[[1]],list[[2]],list[[3]],list[[4]]"

> lisfun <- function (lst) paste( sprintf("list[[%i]]", 1:length(lst)) , collapse=",")
> 
> list1<- as.list(rep(NA,sample(1:10,1)))
> lisfun(list1)
[1] "list[[1]],list[[2]],list[[3]],list[[4]],list[[5]],list[[6]],list[[7]]"
```